# Which folder I use for recovery mysql database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqldump, recovery

[image]

Accidently deleted mysql database and reload again.But ı cant find my old database and no have backup.This is picture that mysql ProgramData folder. Which folder should ı use for recovery? Thanks advice

Comment: Server creates separate folder for each separate database, with the same name. You have dropped database - so both database files and database folder were deleted. Try to recover this deleted folder then try to recover deleted files in it.

Comment: Thanks your answer.As I search databases create backup by itself and maybe it can be related about innodb. Just wonder that how to do it

Answer (score 0):

> Accidently deleted mysql database ...

It happens.
It *shouldn't* be the End of the World.

> ... and reload again.  But I cant find my old database ...

Not sure what you mean by "reload" but if you did anything that involved running "create database" for that particular database then *anything* and *everything* about the *old* database has now been obliterated.

> ... and no have backup.

This is hard lesson for any DBA to learn and, sadly, you've learned it the Hard Way:

> Any Data that you don't have *at least* **two** copies of is Data that you *do not care* about and are perfectly content to *lose*.

You **must** take Backups of your databases, for the very reason that, sometimes, when things go badly wrong, you have to *Recover* them.

*If* you have backups of the machine itself, you *might* be able to get *something* back by restoring the data files from that but *do not* expect to get everything back.  Databases do a *lot* in memory, so any files copied out from "under" a *running* database instance are *not* consistent.

Comment: yeah you are right it should not be end of the world. I know that data is imported but while everything is gonna okey , ı could not reach my local db that one of the my mistake ı write one query statement. It can happen to any person anyway as ı search it can be some solution about that folder. Just would want to ask. Thanks your answer